# ASP.NET Identity core does not create tables

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

I am new to ASP.NET Core. I tried to develop and in ASP.NET Core with this configuration in dbcontext :

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.
            UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True");


    }
```

And here is the startup.cs configuration :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddEntityFramework()
               //.AddSqlServer()
               .AddDbContext<TicketContext>();.....
          }
```

But when I wan to create a user as below:

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "password");
```

, I  get the following error :

> Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'

Updated

With a help of "Alex" in  comments, I did some modifications and now I have these in my project.json now:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
.....
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "DataAccessLayer": "1.0.0-*",
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": "1.0.0-alpha2-final",
    "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
```

But when I run "dotnet ef database update" I got error as below :

"Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'."

Updated

As it seems, when using ef core in first code way, you have to do migration first, so tables are created.

Comment: if you use code first you need to do migration first

Comment: @Alex yes I use codefirst. I ran "dotnet ef database update" in web api project directory and got "No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef""

Comment: if you just enter dotnet in cmd, what you get?

Comment: and you have web api or we application project?

Comment: just try to run it locally and register new user

Comment: yes, link was correct: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs.html#create-a-web-app

Comment: When I ran "dotnet" it shows the the version and command usage. I again ran "dotnet ef database update" and got the error "Check that 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design' has been added to "dependencies" in the startup project ..."

Comment: Add-Migration Initial in Package Manager Console and then Update-Database

Comment: Which project are you running the command in?  Has `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` been added to the same project where your `TicketContext` is?  I noticed you have a `DataAccessLayer` project reference so I'm assuming it's in that project.

Comment: I have dataacesss layer, but only models are defined in that lib, and TicketContext is in webapi project. I ran "Add-Migration Initial" and still get the same error.

Comment: I removed "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" from tools and followed "https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html" and it worked. Thanks @Alex